# Can we make the instance of the decorated object private instead of protected in an abstract decorator?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, decorator

I noticed that most of the examples use protected for the Instance that is being decorated. Could I use private too?

```
public abstract class CoffeeDecorator implements Coffee {
    protected Coffee decoratedCoffee;

    public CoffeeDecorator(Coffee c) {
        this.decoratedCoffee = c;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `protected` makes it available to *subclasses* which mostly is essential in the *Decorator Pattern*. If it was `private` the subclasses then could not access it anymore

Comment: `private` access modified variables/methods aren`t accessible by subclasses.

Comment: You _should_ use `private final` for the instance being decorated and mark the class `final`.

Comment: But why would subclasses access it? The decorators only decorate their own instance, don't they?

Answer (score 3):

Decorator pattern is used as an alternative to the inheritance and helps to add a class additional feature without the need to modify or extends it itself.

I'd decorate it with the `private` property and without the `abstract` class. Demonstrated on a very simple example:

CupOfCoffee.java

```
final class CupOfCoffee implements Coffee {

    public final String prepareCoffee() {
        return "Coffee";
    }
}
```

SugarCoffee.java

```
final class SugarCoffee implements Coffee {

    private final Coffee coffee;

    public SugarCoffee(final Coffee coffee) {
        this.coffee = coffee;
    }

    public final String prepareCoffee() {
        return coffee.prepareCoffee() + " with sugar";
    }
}
```

MilkCoffee.java

```
final class MilkCoffee implements Coffee {

    private final Coffee coffee;

    public MilkCoffee(final Coffee coffee) {
        this.coffee = coffee;
    }

    public final String prepareCoffee() {
        return coffee.prepareCoffee() + " with milk";
    }
}
```

Demo using composable vertical decorators:

```
new MilkCoffee(
    new SugarCoffee(
        new SugarCoffee(
            new Coffee()
        )
    )
).prepareCoffee()           // Coffee with sugar with sugar with milk
```